# how to sync a device calendar for event addition using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, plugins

I am developing a phone gap project with calendar. so i need to add reminder and event( whatever the process could be done in Device calendar). I am looking for Sync up process of Device calendar for both iPhone and Android using phone gap. As i am new to this field, please guide me with Some programming steps of with some examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a JavaScript API to access the Calendar on the target device.

Although PhoneGap does not provide a standard Calendar API (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/index.html), there are community plug-ins that have been created

PhoneGap Calendar plug-in for Android:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/CalendarPlugin

PhoneGap Calendar plug-in for iOS:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/CalendarPlugin

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. but as i am using Xcode to develop a Phonegap project, but i need to build for both android and iPhone. Do i need to add both android and iOS plugins in my project(what u have send for me before).

Answer (score 0):

This is a universal Android/iOS version:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: HI Eddy, Thanks for this great plugin. I want to know that is this plugin synchronize event ? my requirement is that i want to send event from rest api to device . I did add event task by adding button and it is saving event on device caledar but main poblem is that how i will manage deleted event   by web ? it will come by rest api then what login i have to use here .